# How to add a captcha image in angular 8 app?

Tags: angular, recaptcha, captcha

I wand adding an captcha element with image of letters and input for the user,

(I dont want "I am not a robot" version )

like this:

[image]

Is it still supported today?

Comment: We can use Google's recaptcha as well. Here's how  https://link.medium.com/CU15AyCfpsb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin will help you to add CAPTCHA in your application form where you want to prevent access to a BOT

[image: Captcha]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@binssoft/ngx-captcha

Comment: This is not supporting in Angular 15+. You have any alternative for Angular 15+?